# Sum of a column based on value of column from another dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have two df.

```
date <- c("2021-09-27","2021-09-28","2021-09-29","2021-09-30",
          "2021-10-01","2021-10-02","2021-10-03","2021-10-04")
temp <- c(10.5,12.1,11.3,10.2,
          11.3,11.2,10.9,14.1)
df1 <- data.frame(date, temp)
id <- c("id1","id2","id3", "id4")
date_event <- c("2021-09-30","2021-10-01","2021-10-03","2021-10-04")
df2 <- data.frame(id, date_event)
```

I want a new column in df2:

df2$new_column <- #sum from the first value of temp column of df1 until date value of df1 match date_event value of df2

I appreciate any help! Thanks

Comment: What is your desired output? Am I understanding correctly that you are taking the cumulative sum of temperatures?

Answer (score 4):

In base R you vould do

```
merge(df2, transform(df1,temp=cumsum(temp)), by.x="date_event", by.y="date")

date_event  id temp
1 2021-09-30 id1 44.1
2 2021-10-01 id2 55.4
3 2021-10-03 id3 77.5
4 2021-10-04 id4 91.6
```

Comment: @onyamby, your solutions are always so elegant in their simplicity! I learn just by looking at how you use the power of base R. I was going to offer an answer using dplyr's filter, but yours is so simpler and efficient I think.

Comment: @guasi I hope you enjoy learning base R then you could use the other packages

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

Similarly to @onyambu's approach in base R, you could use dplyr to precompute the cumulative totals in `df1` and join those to `df2`.

```
left_join(df2, df1 %>% mutate(temp = cumsum(temp)), 
          by = c("date_event" = "date"))
```

---

Initial approach, less efficient:

If I understand you correctly, this should work, at least for smallish data. First I do a cross join between the two tables to connect every row in df2 with every row in df1, then filter out the ones in df1 that happened later, and then sum the temps for each id/date_event combo. This approach could be costly if you had a large database of id-dater_events, though.

```
df2 %>%
  crossing(df1) %>%
  filter(date <= date_event) %>%
  count(id, date_event, wt = temp)
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 4 × 3
  id    date_event     n
  <chr> <chr>      <dbl>
1 id1   2021-09-30  44.1
2 id2   2021-10-01  55.4
3 id3   2021-10-03  77.5
4 id4   2021-10-04  91.6
```

Comment: You're a wizard! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

additional solution option

```r
library(tidyverse)

df2$temp <- map_dbl(df2$date_event, ~sum(df1$temp[df1$date <= .x]))
df2
#>    id date_event temp
#> 1 id1 2021-09-30 44.1
#> 2 id2 2021-10-01 55.4
#> 3 id3 2021-10-03 77.5
#> 4 id4 2021-10-04 91.6
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

**data.table**

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)

df1[, list(date, temp = cumsum(temp))][df2, on = c("date == date_event")]
#>          date temp  id
#> 1: 2021-09-30 44.1 id1
#> 2: 2021-10-01 55.4 id2
#> 3: 2021-10-03 77.5 id3
#> 4: 2021-10-04 91.6 id4
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>